# how to soql query from ContentDocumentLink for batch?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

i'm struggling with understanding the logic behind this query i need to do for a batch job. i am querying the contentdocumentlink object because i need to capture files (potentially multiple) related to specific campaigns. since its a batch i want to query all campaigns that had files added to it each day and store the URLs of the files for each campaign.

i have:

```
final ID campId;
List<Campaign> campList = [Select Name, Content_Link__c FROM Campaign];

global String soqlQuery = 'Select ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId=:campId';
```

any help means a lot, thanks!

Comment: Please don't delete and repost questions. You're always welcome to [edit] to enhance your post.  Right now, I think this post is likely to be closed because I don't see a specific question articulated.

Comment: You _may_ want a filter on the creation date of the Content Document Link, since you're interested in changes from today.

Comment: This will also work `Select ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (Select Id FROM Campaign)`